# Jquery success message shows even if php form is not validated

Tags: php, jquery, forms, post

I have a php mail form. If the email address does not validate, my jquery updates the emailform div with a success message. I only want the success message to appear if the form is successfully submitted (post).

jquery:

```
  $('#submit').submit(function() { // catch the form's submit event
      $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
          data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
          type: $(this).attr('method'), // GET or POST
          url: $(this).attr('action'), // the file to call
          success: function(response) { // on success..
            console.log(response);
              if(response != 'error; you need to submit the form!'){
              $('#emailform').html("<h2 style='text-align:center;'>Thank you!</h2><hr><p style='text-align:center;'>Thank you for submitting your purchase information.<br>We will send your free gifts soon!</p>"); // update the DIV
            }
          }
      });
      return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting
  });
```

PHP:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
  echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$purchasecode = $_POST['purchasecode'];
$vendor = $_POST['vendor'];


//Validate first
if(empty($_POST['name'])  ||
   empty($_POST['email']) ||
   empty($_POST['purchasecode']) ||
   empty($_POST['vendor']))
{
    echo "All fields are required.";
exit;
}

if(IsInjected($email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit();
}

$email_from = $email;
$email_subject = "GDFY Purchase Confirmation";
$email_body = "New purchase confirmation from $name.\n".
    "Here are the details:\n\n Name: $name \n\n Email: $email \n\n Purchase Code: $purchasecode \n\n Vendor: $vendor";

$to = "idc615@gmail.com";//<== update the email address

$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_from \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: index.html');

// echo "success";


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Did you check out my answer on your other question by any chance? It's a working copy of mine.

Comment: I saw it, but it lost me. My php form works now, but I cant prevent my jquery from updating this div. I'm quite frustrated and a tad bit lost.

Comment: Sometimes you just need to take a wee break from it and come back to it later. Or take another approach and base yourself on what I gave you in your other question. I know things like such can be frustrating. "Been there, done that, got the T-shirt...." ;-) (You'll figure it out)

Comment: Your if statement only checks for one of the possible error messages. Therefore if it isn't that one error message, it thinks it's a success.

Comment: @eloist I just noticed something. In your other question where your form name is `name="contactform"` you have `$('#emailform').html` in your JS here, where it probably should be `$('#contactform').html`

Comment: I tried your code from the other answer and could not get it to work. Guess I'll just live with this bug. Can't seem to find a solution.

Comment: @eloist Did you try my comment just above? Something's not matching.

Comment: @Fred the emailform div is the container for the contactform. It works as intended here. i wanted to flush out the form and replace the container div with the success message.

Comment: @Fred just for kicks, I changed the handler to #contactform, and it does not update my div at all. So, #emailform is the correct

Comment: @eloist I didn't give up on you (lol) have a look at my answer below.

Comment: @eloist What I suggest then is to get rid of your `IsInjected` function altogether, since `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` will take care of that, and use `if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { die("The email <b>$email</b> you entered, is not valid."); exit; }` instead, that alone was a major problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have something going  that will work for you, but you will need to first download two files, which is where I got the JS/demo/tutorial from.

Source: http://webdesign.torn.be/tutorials/javascript/prototype/forms-with-prototype/

1) http://webdesign.torn.be/tutorials/assets/images/loading_indicator.gif

2) http://webdesign.torn.be/tutorials/assets/js/prototype.js

Plus this:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit"  id="submitButton" value="Submit" class="mainButton">SUBMIT</button>
```

Should use this instead:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit"  id="submitButton" value="Submit" class="mainButton">
```

### jQuery conflict

If you must use jQuery, try the following:

```
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Or

```
<script src="prototype.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
// Give $ back to prototype.js; create new alias to jQuery.
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

### HTML form (tested)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
// <![CDATA[
document.observe('dom:loaded', function() {

    function sendForm(event){
        // we stop the default submit behaviour
        Event.stop(event);
        var oOptions = {
            method: "POST",
            parameters: Form.serialize("contactForm"),
            asynchronous: true,
            onFailure: function (oXHR) {
                $('feedback').update(oXHR.statusText);
            },
            onLoading: function (oXHR) {
                $('feedback').update('Sending data ... <img src="loading_indicator.gif" title="Loading..." alt="Loading..." border="0" />');
            },                          
            onSuccess: function(oXHR) {
               $('feedback').update(oXHR.responseText);
            }               
        };
        var oRequest = new Ajax.Updater({success: oOptions.onSuccess.bindAsEventListener(oOptions)}, "mail_form.php", oOptions);             
    }
    Event.observe('submitButton', 'click', sendForm, false);

}); 
// ]]>
</script>

</head>

<body>
<div id="feedback"> </div>
<div id="contact">

            <h2>Confirm your purchase information</h2>
            <hr>
            <form method="post" id="contactForm" name="contactform" action="">
            <p>
            <label for='name'>Your Name:</label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="name">
            </p>
            <p>
            <label for='email'>Email Address:</label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="email">
            </p>
            <p>
            <label for='purchasecode'>Purchase Code:</label> <br>
            <input type="text" name="purchasecode">
            </p>
            <p>
            <label for='vendor'>Vendor Name:</label> <br>
            <select name="vendor">
              <option value="1" selected="selected"></option>
              <option value="2" >Amazon</option>
              <option value="3" >Barnes &amp; Noble</option>
              <option value="4" >Family Christian</option>
              <option value="5" >Christianbook.com</option>
              <option value="6" >LifeWay</option>
              <option value="7" >Books-A-Million</option>
              <option value="8" >Mardel</option>
            </select>
            </p>

<input type="submit" name="submit"  id="submitButton" value="Submit" class="mainButton"><br>

</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

### PHP handler (mail_form.php) EDITED

**Note:** change `$to = "email@example.com";` to your Email address

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
  echo "Error, you need to submit the form!";
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$purchasecode = $_POST['purchasecode'];
$vendor = $_POST['vendor'];

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

die("The email <b>$email</b> you entered, is not valid.");
exit;
}

//Validate first
if(empty($_POST['name'])  ||
   empty($_POST['email']) ||
   empty($_POST['purchasecode']) ||
   empty($_POST['vendor']))
{
    echo "All fields are required.";
exit;
}

if(IsInjected($email))
{

    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit();
}

$email_from = $email;
$email_subject = "GDFY Purchase Confirmation";
$email_body = "New purchase confirmation from $name.\n".
    "Here are the details:\n\n Name: $name \n\n Email: $email \n\n Purchase Code: $purchasecode \n\n Vendor: $vendor";

$to = "email@example.com"; //<== update the email address

$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_from \r\n";
//Send the email!

mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
// header('Location: index.html');

echo "Success";

// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Unfortunately, the same thing happens. When I try and use a purposely unvalidated email it still reloads my div with the success message.

Comment: @eloist Give me a few minutes, I'll fix that. It has to do in the PHP handler.

Comment: I forgot to add the loading icon and prototype.js, did that, and now I am getting a document has no method ready error. My buttons do not work anymore.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'

Comment: Ok, so somehow prototype,js breaks my $(document).ready If I remove prototype.js from the head, the buttons work again, and my scripts load.

Comment: @eloist Ok, reload this page and see my edit in the PHP handler and try it again.

Comment: @eloist You will have to use ALL my code here and not yours. It's a worked copy of what you have and it worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Will this still break my jquery?

Comment: @eloist Don't use jQuery, it's not needed.

Comment: @eloist If you must use jQuery, put `prototype.js` above it so that it's the first loaded, then load jQuery, see if that helps. It should. After the jQuery, put this under it `jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: I have other elements on the site that using jquery, so unfortunately, it's a requirement for me. I'm going to play with this and see where it takes me. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: @eloist Have a look at my other edit, under **jQuery conflict**

Comment: @eloist I just added another jQuery conflict option just now. Try both and see. Replace `jquery.js` with yours.